# How to rsync content from another machine through multiple machines?

Tags: shell-script, ssh, scripting, rsync, bashrc

I have 4 linux machines having name **A,B,C,D** and I want to rsync some content from machine **A** machine **D**, but *A is not directly connected to D* and but *A is connected to B* and *B is connected to C* and *C is connected to D*.
So I want to run a script in A that do rsync some content from A to B  then B to C and then C to D.

Comment: Do you use the same account for all of A B C D?
Do you have ssh key access setup ?
I have a nice solution if you can say yes to both above

Comment: I have same ac for A,B,C,D and I can setup key access, so what is the solution ? help me

Answer (score 0):

Use could use SSH Jump Hosts to establish connection from A to D: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts#Jump_Hosts_--_Passing_Through_a_Gateway_or_Two

Answer (score 0):

The solution is a scary-looking ProxyCommand you should add to your `~/.ssh/config file

I could not manage to make it look good in this message, so please get it from there https://hastebin.com/doqekujalu.tex

Once you add those lines to ( the end of ) your youruserhomedir/.ssh/config file on machine A
you can use A+B+C notation to denote the route your connection should go:

```
rsync /some/file  B+C+D:/remote/path/on_Dhost/
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to run rsync in daemon mode on machines B and C.  In daemon mode, you can specify a command to run before the module is executed.

Modify machine B:

```
user@B:/etc/rsyncd.conf

pre-xfer exec = rsync [options] C
```

And then daisy chain from C to D:

```
user@C:/etc/rsyncd.conf

pre-xfer exec = rsync [options] D
```

Execute rsync from machine A to B... runs rsync to machine B to machine C... and then onto D.

Incidentally the "post-xfer exec" option is available as well.

Comment: As you said **Execute rsync from machine A to B... runs rsync to machine B to machine C... and then onto D** is  simple as said , its doesnt required anything and presently  I am doing the same. But I want to rsync content from A to D in a single command or script

Comment: As I understand it, rsync can only connect one hop.  As such, I don't think it's possible to configure rsync to do what you ask given the conditions of not modifying any of the daisy chained remote hosts.  It may be possible to export the rsync-ed directory structures in NFS and mount them so that your local rsync can reach the further hops.  However, NFS has some special security related issues... You seem to currently have a solution.  It may be the best (and only possible) solution already, even if seemingly inelegant.....  But, I've been known to wrong before.